# How to connect different tables with same ID?

Tags: mysql, export

Is it possible to connect the content of different MyISAM tables?
All those tables have the ID column (primary key) in common for entries which belong together.

Database type of tables: MyISAM
Table 1: ID (primary key) / Name / Surname
Table 2: ID (primary key) / Age

I am using phpmyadmin / Sequel Pro. And I am using PDO to query and update the tables.
Do I need to link those tables or is there an export functions which combines the entries (based on the ID) of different tables automatically during export?

For now I setup the ID as primary key but didn't linked tables to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use query to show results:

```
SELECT table1.ID, name, surname, age
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

or create view

```
CREATE VIEW fullView 
AS 
SELECT table1.ID, name, surname, age
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

Comment: That sounds good! Thank you Marek.